# Autoresizing UITextField in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, autoresize

I have a UIScrollView that doesn't use auto layout, and a UITextField in it. I would like to make it so that my textfield automatically resizes based on the width of the view. How?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can grab the size of the scrollview then based on that use the width (I'm assuming that's what you need) to size your textfield. Like so:

```
CGSize scrollSize = myScrollView.bounds.size;
UITextField *myField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                               CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollSize.width * 0.75, 20)];
```

This would make a text field that spans 75% of the view width.